# How do I cancel a long running Ruby Net::SSH command

Tags: ruby, ssh, net-ssh

If I kick off a long running command like a database dump using `exec`, how would I go about canceling that command on the remote host if, for example, the user start mashing Control-C to kill the script.

In my testing it seems like even if you Control-C and kill the application the remote command keeps running.

Answer (score 0):

Capture SIGINT and SystemExit and clean up:

```
rescue SystemExit, Interrupt
  # clean up
  # net-ssh execute a kill on the pid
  # raise error
end
```

Comment: Wouldn't that just kill the Ruby process and not a process it started on a remote host? I guess you could replace Process.kill with whatever remote command would kill the process.  Also you'd want to raise the error after rescuing it, right?

Comment: Thanks, @keithrbennett, code example edited based on your suggestions.